# Does Key Exist in VBA Userform TreeView

Tags: vba, treeview, userform

In a VBA treeview userform, how can I tell if a node exists by key, or anything else?

Is there a good way to see if a node exists?

```
Public Sub Test
  Dim thisNode as New Node

  ' Determine if node exists
  If tvNodeExample.Nodes.Item("TestKey") is Nothing Then
    msgbox "Node Does Not Exist"
  Else
    Set thisNode = tvNodeExample.Nodes.Item("TestKey")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/foldertreeview.aspx

Comment: @DavidZemens, I'm not seeing anything at the page that discusses a way to tell if a node already exists in a tree view.  In that page, the code recursively calls itself, but a reference to the parent node is passed recursively.  I may have misread something, but I'm not seeing an answer to my question there.

Comment: I did some more searching, `.Nodes` is a collection object, and some threads suggest there is no built-in method to check whether an item exists within a collection, without resorting to error trapping.  The method you provided below will work. Just remember to `On Error GoTo 0` after your `If Err.Number...` line to restore error handling.  Otherwise, you might try to see if `.Contains` is a valid method  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172935(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much searching, I've found what to me is an acceptable answer, although I don't like the implementation.  When setting a node object based on the key, if that node doesn't exist, you receive error number 35601.  Thus, the following code works.

```
Public Sub Test()
  Dim thisNode as Node

  ' Determine if node exists

  ' Disable error handling temporairily
  On Error Resume Next
  Set thisNode = tvNodeExample.Nodes.Item("testKey")
  If Err.Number = 35601 Then

    On Error Goto ErrorHandler      

    ' Create the node
    Set thisNode = tvNodeExample.Add(, tvwFirst, "testKey", "test Description")
  End If

  On Error Goto ErrorHandler

  ' Do Stuff      

End Sub
```